# SdWebImage download thumbnail and then download high resolution

Tags: objective-c, sdwebimage

I want to set a thumbnail image url and high res image url so that first thumbnail image is downloaded and then the high res image is downloaded

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you don't need to create any hidden `UIImageView` to do the trick.

What you must do is set the first URL (with the smaller image) to be directly downloaded into your `UIImageView`, and then use `SDWebImageManager` to download the larger version on the background. When it finishes download, simply set the downloaded image in your image view.

Here's how you can do that:

```
// First let the smaller image download naturally
[self.imageView setImageWithURL:self.imageURL];

// Slowly download the larger version of the image
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadWithURL:self.currentPhoto.largeImageURL options:SDWebImageLowPriority progress:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {
    if (image) {
        [self.imageView setImage:image];
    }
}];
```

Note how I used `SDWebImageLowPriority` option. This way, the image (which should be naturally larger than the first one) will be downloaded in a low priority and should not cancel the first download.

Comment: I don't see why not. Just make sure you cancel the requests after a cell gets out of bounds, so you don't end up reusing that cell later

Answer (score 3):

It's late but i solved my problem with following code

```
UIImageView * hiddenImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

[hiddenImageView sd_setImageWithURL:thumbUrl completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {

    if (image) {

        mImageView.image = image;
    }

    if (originalUrl != nil) {

        [mImageView sd_setImageWithURL:originalUrl placeholderImage:image completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL){

            if (image) {

                mImageView.image = image; // optional
            }

        }];

    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Download to a hidden UIImageView somewhere on the view, and then switch between the two when its done loading, via:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL     
URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
   completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {... completion code here ...}];
```